# Can I avoid to call controller twice in my Rspec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I would like to avoid a dual call in my controller tests, for better performance.
I'm using Rails.

My test goes like this:

```ruby
before { get :index }
it { expect(response).not_to be_successful }
it { expect(Bugsnag).to receive(:notify)
after { get :index }
```

What I'd like to have is something like the following, where I'd only have a single call to `GET #index`

```ruby
it { expect(Bugsnag).to receive(:notify)
before { get :index }
it { expect(response).not_to be_successful }
```

Issue I'm having is that `expect(class).to receive(:message)` needs to be called before `get :index`.

How do I set this? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using a [partial double](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies):

```
before do
  allow(Bugsnag).to receive(:notify)
  get :index
end
subject { response }
it { should_not be_successful }
it "notifies Bugsnag" do
  expect(Bugsnatch).to have_received(:notify)
end
```

Comment: On a side note - `it { should_not be_successful }` is not a very good way to test a "failure" scenario since it will pass if the app is broken. Instead you want to test that app returns the correct response code like 401 or 403 and / or redirects.

Answer (score 0):

More lines of code, but:

- no double call of `get :index`
- every example now has a description

-

```
it 'is not successful' do
  get :index
  expect(response).not_to be_successful
end

it 'notifies someone' do
  expect(Bugsnag).to receive(:notify)
  get :index
end
```

Comment: So, there is no way I can get rid of one `get :index` call, you're saying?

Comment: in your example in fact you're calling it not 2, but 4 times (before and after each request x 2)